# How would I approach building an ios8 custom keyboard to select images

Tags: ios, ios8

A while back I was asked to build a custom keyboard to select images for e.g. Messaging apps. I thought it wasn't possible because the other person would not have the character set but then I saw http://popkey.co.

I can create an interface easily enough but how would I get an image to be output by the keyboard and sent into an application like iMessage? How would this work for a regular text field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Popkey just puts the gif in the pasteboard and the user can paste it into iMessage. It won't work in every app but I think iMessage (and maybe even WhatsApp) can deliver images which are pasted in the textfield.

In fact **it doesn't copy it directly in iMessage**

But it won't work with any regular textfield which can't handle images,

You can see the behaviour in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCGpwn_YL_c at [00:07](http://youtu.be/sCGpwn_YL_c?t=7s)

You can copy an image to the pasteboard using the `UIPasteBoard` API

Comment: Right. All that a keyboard *officially* supports is passing text back to the calling text field. Any different behavior won't work everywhere.

Comment: @AzzUrr1 ... are you saying that PopKey does not even "put the image in to the SMS" for you?  i.e. it just "copies" it, and then the user has to hit paste in the normal way .. is that right?   thanks!

Comment: Yes that is right. It won't work for SMS only iMessage or MMS